# Dont get returned list of files in temp folder on Domino server via agent

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a LotusScript agent, signed with proper ID to have full access rights on server. The agent should return a list of files in the temporary folder. Ultimately I would this agent to clean a specific folder here.

The problem is that the agent does not return a list of files although I know that files are there!

I wondering if I am dealing with some form of restriction (and how to pass by it) or if my code is incorrect (how to correct it).

The code is mostly inspired by in IBM support note.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-dir-function-recursive-lotusscript

Here is the code

Comment:    [Not Assigned]
Shared Agent:   Yes
Type:   LotusScript
State:  Disabled
Trigger:    Scheduled
Interval:   On Schedule More Than Once A Day
Acts On:    None
LotusScript Code:

```
%REM
    Agent cleanupTempCatalogAlt2
    Created Sep 13, 2019 by §Patrick §Kwinten/Designer/ACME
    Description: Comments for Agent
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare
Dim sess As NotesSession
Dim agent As NotesAgent
Sub Initialize  
    Dim sess As New NotesSession
    Set agent = sess.CurrentAgent
    Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " - Starting ")  
    ScanDirs("D:\IBM\Domino\Temp\notes53F5BD\xspupload")    
End Sub
Sub ScanDirs(path As String) 
    Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " - Start ScanDirs") 
    Dim sess As New NotesSession
    Dim DirList As Variant
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim sep As String
    If path <> "" Then
        If InStr(sess.Platform, "Windows") > 0 Then 
            sep = "\"
        Else 
            sep = "/" 
        End If
        ReDim DirList(0)
        If InStr(path, sep) > 0 Then 
            filepath = StrLeftBack(path, sep)
        End If 
        Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " filepath - " + filepath)   
        Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " path - " + path)   
        filename = Dir(path, 16)
        While filename <> "" 
            Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " filename - " + filename)   
            If filename <> "." And filename <> ".." Then 
                Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " filepath & sep & filename - " + filepath & sep & filename) 
                If (GetFileAttr(filepath & sep & filename) And 16) > 0 Then 
                    DirList = ArrayAppend(DirList,filepath & sep & filename & sep) 
                Else 
                    Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " - Got file?")  
                    ' PERFORM DESIRED CHECK/OPERATION
                    ' ON filepath & sep & filename
                    ' OR filename (as desired) 
                End If
            End If 
            filename = Dir
        Wend
        Print("### PK " + agent.Name + " DirList - " + DirList(0))  
    DirList = FullTrim(DirList) 
    ForAll dirpath In DirList 
    ScanDirs(dirpath)
    End ForAll
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting "Runtime security level" to 2 or 3 in agent properties.

[image]

Comment: Hi Per, I am running with that option but still I got en empty list returned

Comment: Your agent runs fine on my test server and prints to the console the file names of all the files in the directory that I tested it on

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Domino you are running and what platform? 
Could the problem be here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO78281

> upgrading to SLES11, the "dir$" function in LotusScript does
>   not see
>   directories and files within mounted shares anymore.

We didn't have chance to change linux-version so the problem was solved by syncing folder to server. Thereby we could remove files, and syncing takes care of the rest.